# Can you give an example of $\bigcup\limits_{C \in \mathscr P} C=X$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I don't grasp what really  $\bigcup\limits_{C \in \mathscr P} C=X$ is in the following definition.

> Definition 5. Let $X$ be a nonempty set. By a partition $\mathscr P$ of $X$ we mean a set of nonempty subsets of $X$ such that
>   (a) If $A, B \in \mathscr P$ and $A \neq B$, then $A \cap B = \emptyset$, (b) $\bigcup\limits_{C \in \mathscr P} C=X$
>   Source: Set Theory by You-Feng Lin. Shwu-Yeng T.Lin

Comment: A partition is a collection of subsets which are pairwise disjoint and whose union is everything.  Basically, you're dividing up your space into disjoint pieces which fit together to create all of your original space (the covering of the entire original space is the union that you're describing).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I understand what sets are disjoint, **A and B are disjoint** **$\Leftrightarrow A \cap B = Ø$** but what does sets are "pairwise disjoint" mean?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}$ is a collection of sets, if you take any two distinct sets, then their intersection is empty.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I know that. But what do you mean by "pairwise" as in "pairwise disjoint"?

Comment: That is the definition of *pairwise disjoint* for a collection of sets: In a collection of sets, every pair is disjoint.  $\mathcal{P}$ is a set of sets.  So the elements of $\mathcal{P}$ are sets and all pairs of sets in $\mathcal{P}$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way to think about it. Let $\mathscr{P}$ be a family of non-empty subsets of a set $X$. Then $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition of $X$ if it satisfies two conditions:

- every $x\in X$ belongs to at most one of the sets in $\mathscr{P}$, and
- every $x\in X$ belongs to at least one of the sets in $\mathscr{P}$.

The first of these is just an informal verbal version of your condition (a): if $A,B\in\mathscr{P}$, and $A\ne B$, then $A\cap B=\varnothing$. If some $x\in X$ belonged to more than one of the sets in $\mathscr{P}$, say $A$ and $B$ with $A\ne B$, then we’d have $x\in A\cap B$, and $A\cap B$ would *not* be empty. Conversely, if there were distinct $A$ and $B$ in $\mathscr{P}$ such that $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$, then any of the elements of $A\cap B$ would belong to more than one of the sets in $\mathscr{P}$.

The second is an informal version of your condition (b): $\bigcup_{C\in\mathscr{P}}C=X$. The union $\bigcup_{C\in\mathscr{P}}C$ is just the union of all of the sets in the collection $\mathscr{P}$. Each $C\in\mathscr{P}$ is a subset of $X$, so the elements of these sets $C$ are elements of the set $X$. The union of these sets is therefore the collection of all elements of $X$ that belong to at least one of the sets in the family $\mathscr{P}$, and (b) says that this is all of $X$: *every* member of $X$ belongs to at least one of the sets $C$ in the family $\mathscr{P}$.

Put the two together, and you can see that a partition of $X$ is a family $\mathscr{P}$ of non-empty subsets of $X$ with the property that each $x\in X$ belongs to *exactly one* of the sets in the family $\mathscr{P}$. The partition $\mathscr{P}$ is a division of $X$ into non-overlapping subsets (that’s the first condition) that include every member of $X$ (that’s the second condition).

For a very simple example, take $X$ to be $\Bbb Z^+$, the set of positive integers. Let $E$ be the set of even positive integers and $O$ the set of odd positive integers. Then $\{E,O\}$ is a partition of $\Bbb Z^+$, because the sets $E$ and $O$ are non-empty, $E\cap O=\varnothing$ (the first condition), and $E\cup O=\Bbb Z^+$ (the second condition). Here $\bigcup_{C\in\{E,O\}}C$ is just $E\cup O$.

For a more substantial example, note that each positive integer $n$ can be written uniquely in the form $n=2^km$, where $k$ is a non-negative integer, and $m$ is odd. (For example, $1=2^0\cdot1$, $8=2^3\cdot1$, and $12=2^2\cdot3$.) Call $m$ the *odd part* of $n$. For each $m\in O$ let $A_m$ be the set of positive integers whose odd part is $m$. (Thus, $A_1$ is the set of powers of $2$, $A_3$ is the set of positive integers of the form $3\cdot2^k$ for some non-negative integer $k$, and so on.) Let $\mathscr{P}=\{A_m:m\in O\}$.

- If $\ell$ and $m$ are distinct odd positive integers, $A_\ell\cap A_m=\varnothing$, so the family $\mathscr{P}$ satisfies the first condition: no positive integer is in more than one of the sets $A_m$. We say that the family $\mathscr{P}$ is *pairwise disjoint*, meaning that each pair of its members is disjoint.
- Every positive integer $n$ belongs to at least one $A_m$: we just divide out any factors of $2$ in $n$, and if $m$ is the remaining factor, then $n\in A_m$. Starting with $n=1000$, for instance, I can divide out $3$ factors of $2$, getting successively $500,250$, and $125$, and I find that $1000\in A_{125}$. Thus, $$\Bbb Z^+=A_1\cup A_3\cup A_5\cup A_7\cup\ldots=\bigcup_{m\in O}A_m=\bigcup_{C\in\mathscr{P}}C\;.$$ We say that the family $\mathscr{P}$ *covers* $\Bbb Z^+$, meaning that every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ belongs to at least one member of $\mathscr{P}$.

Between the two conditions we have that each positive integer belongs to exactly one of the sets $A_m\in\mathscr{P}$: $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition of $\Bbb Z^+$.